# Xcode GUI Design: Opening a El Capitan Storyboard file in Yosemite

Tags: xcode, osx-elcapitan, xcode-storyboard

Is it possible to to create a storyboard-based app in OS X El Capitan 10.11 and open it in Yosemite *with the same xCode Version* (7.3.1)

I get the following warning:

[image: Xcode warning when opening 10.11 storyboard in 10.10]

I've tried changing settings in file inspector - without luck. Builds for is set to 'deployment target 10.9' and opens in to 'Xcode 7'

Has anyone dealt with this scenario already?

---

UPDATE: This seems to be related to stack views...  If I remove all stack views, the .storyboard file no longer has the  tag as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.Cocoa.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="10117" systemVersion="15G31" targetRuntime="MacOSX.Cocoa" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" initialViewController="B8D-0N-5wS">
    <dependencies>
        <deployment version="1090" identifier="macosx"/>
        <development version="7000" identifier="xcode"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.CocoaPlugin" version="10117"/>
        <capability name="stacking Non-gravity area distributions on NSStackView" minToolsVersion="7.0" minSystemVersion="10.11"/>
    </dependencies>
    ...
```

I don't understand this behaviour: If stack views are not fully supported or don't behave the same way earlier OS versions, there should at least be warning when I choose "deployment target 10.9"! Better yet, Xcode should disable the stack views altogether if that's the case!

Comment: NSStackview was first introduced in SDK 10.9 so I would expect them to work for 10.9 targets. see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstackview